# Windows: Loading Haskell-Source-Code into ghci

Tags: haskell, loading, interpreter, ghci

I am a newbie to Haskell and my problem is probably very trivial, yet I do not know how to solve it.

I created a minimal source code (for faculty, as in the tutorial) with the Editor in Windows 7, then saved it as "test.hs" . Now if I try to load the file into the Haskell interpreter (ghci), then it will give me the following error message:

: can't find file S:\Haskell-Code\test.hs 
Failed. modules loaded: none.

I am sure that I am in the right directory, I also tried loading test (which gives me another error message telling me that it isn't a module), also renamed the file to just "test". Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file should definitely be called "*.hs". Provided you are in the directory, where the file lives (i.e. you started ghci there), :load test.hs should work. In that case ghci should not complain with a full path even if you get the filename wrong.

Comment: I also supposed that it should work, however, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you start ghci (in the right directory) and then type

:!dir

- Does it display the right directory?
- Do you see the file test.hs?

Comment: Thanks!Yes, It does find the file, however it is text.hs.txt
That's probably the problem. Is there a way to get the ".txt"-ending away (it is not in the filename itself)?

Comment: @Yinyue: Do you start ghci in `cmd` or Powershell? In this case you can use `move test.hs.txt test.hs`. However, you can also simply show file extensions and edit the file in explorer. The setting can be found in the view menu.

Comment: as a fast hack you can type :!move test.hs.txt test.hs